# Work-Around for variable length array declaration can not have 'static' error

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

Hello: trying to figure a work-around for the above referenced error which is requiring a hard-coded integer in subscript declaration for static array `arInterpolateFin`.

I've tried local variables inside `ProcessSamples` but I still receive error. The calling code object which will be recipient of return array is local `malloc` array.

Any suggestions? I'd like to keep this construct as it processes many elements very quickly.

```
(SInt16*) ProcessSamples:(SInt16)arBufferRaw : (int) numSamples;
{
    int tmpInt = numSamples
    static SInt16 arInterpolateFin[tmpInt];//4201930

    for (int i = 0; i<(95); i++ )
    {
        arInterpolateFin[tmp1st]=10000;
        tmp1st+=44099;
    }
    return arInterpolateFin;
}
```

Comment: The example you show is objective C, not C.  I was gong to suggest verifying that your compiler is set to use ANSI C99 extensions, but I am not that would apply to objective C?

Comment: In C99 or C11, you could not have a VLA that is static. The two concepts (static and VLA) are mutually exclusive. Using `static` says 'size fixed at program start-up and preserved thereafter', whereas VLA says 'size potentially changes each time the function is called'. You can't have global VLAs (same reason). You can't initialize VLAs; you can't return VLAs (meaningfully); you can only use them in the current function or pass them to called functions. If those constraints aren't appropriate, don't use a VLA. Note that `const int a_size = 100; int a[a_size];` is a VLA in C (but not C++).

Comment: @ryyker Well, Objective-C is a proper, strict superset of C (optionally insert "your argument is invalid" meme here).

Comment: As Jonathan indicates, in vanilla C when you declare something "static" that means that space for the variable is effectively allocated inside your program -- the exact amount of space you need for the static variable is "reserved" when your program "loads", and before it begins to execute.  So the size of any static array must be pre-defined as some sort of literal value.

Comment: Is `arInterpolateFin` being indexed outside its bounds with `arInterpolateFin[tmp1st]=...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meet `malloc()`. The `static` keyword doesn't really make any sense here.

```
SInt16 *arr = malloc(numSamples * sizeof(arr[0]));
```

Don't forget to `free()` the returned pointer inside the caller when you don't need it anymore.

Also, I don't see what purpose the `tmpInt` variable serves. It's just makes the code harder to follow.

Comment: I've got code working without issue by adding malloc and releasing after return statement. The calling code object is an int that receives pointer to newly populated array. can I effectively free arInterpolateFin after return statement?

Comment: return arInterpolateFin;                           
    free(arInterpolateFin);

Comment: @Mickey - no you cannot free after the return statement! (a) the statement is never executed, which saves you from (b) if you free the array it is gone and the returned pointer is no longer valid. If you are using malloc & free you need to free *after* you've completely finished using the array.

Comment: Absolutely right you are! I set calling variable to point to return array(arInterplateFin) and then free that memory when appropriate. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @Mickey You are welcome, I'm glad you have solved the problem (and now you hopefully understand it in detail).

Answer (score 1):

You write "The calling code object which will be recipient of return array is local malloc array." which doesn't make sense as it is - you return a *pointer* to a static array, not an array itself.

Furthermore allocating a permanent (`static`) array which changes sizes on each function call just doesn't make sense - C arrays are given a size at creation and that size cannot be changed thereafter.

Are you attempting to set some initial values in an array by calling a method? If so pass the array into the method:

```
(void) initProcessSamples:(SInt16 *)arInterpolateFin
{
    int tmp1st = 0; // 0 is just a guess

    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++)
    {
        arInterpolateFin[tmp1st] = 10000;
        tmp1st += 44099;
    }
    return;
}
```

HTH

Comment: Ok, I used an int array object in calling code to receive pointer from called code but had to invoke malloc in called code to work around static issue